# how to use render's second parameter 'locals' on script in pug file?

Tags: javascript, pug

hello first thank you for your help to my first question in stackoverflow.

my qeustion is "how to use render's second parameter 'locals' on script in pug file".

in index.js...

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  Movie.find({}).then((movies)=>{
    res.render('index', {movies:movies});
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

in index.pug...

```
extends layout
block content
  ul
  each movie in movies
    li
      a(href='/edit/'+movie._id) #{movie.title}
      script(type='text/javascript').
        console.log(movie)
```

and the console.log output is "uncatched reference error: movie is not defiend".

on "a(href='/edit/'+movie._id) #{movie.title}" the movie is working but,
on "console.log(movie)" it's not.

i think scope is not matter and the declaration also no problem.

what is problem? and how can i use the locals on script in pug file?

one more time, really thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's undefined. Understand what is happening :

- Pug is rendering an HTML file. Meaning, it's a template, that you fill with values. Pug is going to "bake" all this and output an HTML file. Good.
- This file contains a line of code, as text : `console.log(movie)`. Very well.
- Now, this HTML file is sent to the browser, where it is parsed, an the code executed.
  The browser starts executing the code, sees `console.log(movie)` and says "What the heck is `movie`?" Crash : `movie is undefined`.

This is the difference between server-side and client-side environments. Your file is being created on the server, but executed in a browser, a totally different environment in a totally different machine. There's no way `movie` is defined there.

Comment: what a easy to understand your answer is. really thank you for your help. i didn't understand front environment exactly and try to look for the cause in the wrong place. thank you!!